# The relation between the curvature of level curve along the normal direction.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, curves, curvature

Illustrate my problem with figure:

[image]
For a given curve (solid line '-'). $\phi$ is the signed distance function of curve,  $n$ is the normal vector at $\phi^{-1} = 0$, the dashed line '--' is the level curve with distance $\eta$.

Define $\kappa$ is the curvature of level curve, I want find the relation between curvature of $\kappa(x)$ and $\kappa(y)$ where $y = x + \eta n$. More detailed, I want express the relation by the form of 
$ \kappa(y) = a \kappa(x) + O(\eta^2) $ 
where $a$ is constant or geometry on given curve.

For a simple example. Let curve $\phi^{-1}=0$ is a circle with radius of $r$. Then we have $ \kappa(y) = (1 + \eta \kappa(x) )^{-1} \kappa(x)$
since $\kappa(x) = \frac{1}{r}$, and $\kappa(y) = \kappa(x+\eta n) = \frac{1}{r+\eta}$.

I have try to expansion by Taylor expansion, $\kappa(y) = \kappa(x) + \eta n \cdot \nabla \kappa + O(\eta^2)$. But I want more simple formula since $\nabla \kappa$ is complex to calculate in my problem.

Is there some books or reference recommend for this kind problem? Thanks

Comment: In general, you are talking about parallel curves in the plane if you go a fixed normal distance $\eta$ at each point. It's easier than to work parametrically (say, assuming the original curve is arclength-parametrized).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only intuition, no prove:
I'll write $\kappa_\eta(t)$ to denote the curvature of $t\mapsto c(t)+\eta n(t)$ at $t$, where $c$ is the initial curve. By using
\begin{equation}|\kappa|=R^{-1},
\end{equation} where $R$ is the radius of the best fitting circle, we get (always for $\eta$ small enough)
\begin{equation}\kappa_\eta=-(R+\eta)^{-1}=\frac{-|\kappa|}{1+\eta |\kappa|}=\frac{\kappa}{1-\eta \kappa}
\end{equation}
for points with initial negative curvature $\kappa$ and
\begin{equation}\kappa_\eta=(R-\eta)^{-1}=\frac{|\kappa|}{1-\eta |\kappa|}=\frac{\kappa}{1-\eta \kappa}
\end{equation}
for points with initial positive curvature $\kappa.$
So in general (for $\eta$ small enough)
\begin{equation}\kappa_\eta=\frac{\kappa}{1-\eta \kappa}=\kappa\sum_{i=0}^\infty (\kappa \eta)^i=\kappa+\kappa^2\eta+\kappa^3\eta^2+...
\end{equation}